# How do you fix proxy issue in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy

I've been through different quidelines and I don't find anything that really works on this problem. So in my desperate time, I'm writing here to see if theres any luck.

I've never used Visual Studio Code before, and as I can see it's a new thing, compared to Microsoft Visual Studio..
However as much as I like the sleek look of VSC, whenever I try troubleshooting the code I get the message that says **"localhost refused to connect to network"** (something like that)

I've seen various pages talking about proxy username and password, problem is, I don't actually use proxy on my computer, so how do I actually find that? I've been under the network settings to see if I could change something with the proxy, but theres no change..

I've tried to download an "ignore proxy" app to VSC, to no avail..

My question is, what am I missing, what am I doing wrong, what will work?

my **settings.json** looks like this:

```html
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Abyss",
 
    "http.proxy": "",
    "http.proxyAuthorization": null,
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": true,
    "http.proxySupport": "override"
}
```

Picture of the screen (its in danish)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or5sA.png)

Comment: If you're not using a proxy, why are you setting it up? Or am I missing something?

Comment: im not setting it up, it complained that the proxy was in the way for the VSC to run a view of the website, and I'm not sure why it does that, or how to fix it